# "hookup: not found" during git rebase, can't figure out why

Tags: git

I'm getting errors like this in a project:

```
$ git rebase otherbranch
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Foo
Applying: Bar
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
hookup resolve-schema .merge_file_eZf29j .merge_file_Yuvarz .merge_file_52DZ32 7: 1: hookup resolve-schema .merge_file_eZf29j .merge_file_Yuvarz .merge_file_52DZ32 7: hookup: not found
fatal: Failed to execute internal merge
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 Bar
```

It's an old and shared project inside a VM, so it may well have all sorts of mysterious configuration. I suspect something is configured to look for [tpope/hookup](https://github.com/tpope/hookup), but I can't find any mention of it in the list of Ruby gems, or the project Gemfile, or the `.git/hooks` directory, or my ~/.gitconfig, so I'm not sure where else to look. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the `.git/config` file and the `.git/hooks/post-checkout` hook if they contain anything. At least that’s what I see is being modified when installing hookup.

Comment: Thank you. I grepped the entire file system and indeed found it in `.git/config`: it had `[merge "railsschema"]\n\tdriver = hookup resolve-schema %A %O %B %L` for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the [install routine](https://github.com/tpope/hookup/blob/master/lib/hookup.rb#L48), hookup will do two things:

1. Add a line to the `post-checkout` hook (stored at `.git/hooks/post-checkout`).
2. Setup a `merge=railsschema` attribute in `.git/info/attributes`.
3. Add a `merge.railsschema.driver` section to the repository’s config file (stored at `.git/config`).

Undoing these changes should completely remove hookup from the repository. Actually just removing the line from the post-checkout hook should work fine, since that’s what starts the whole process. And the [built-in removal](https://github.com/tpope/hookup/blob/master/lib/hookup.rb#L64) does the same.

Comment: Thank you. I don't actually have the gem installed (but I guess someone did at some point), so I can't run the built-in removal, but it's good to know what it does. As I described in a comment above, what fixed it for me was removing the `"railsschema"` section from `.git/config`.